# "fuzzy" not working in "query_string" query

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I have a requirement for the user to pass in a string which is searched against elasticsearch (5.6, can't update). The string might be a simple "michael" or "firstName:Michael". I want to be able to provide a flag to enable the query to be fuzzy. For this reason I DO NOT want to use the fuzzy operator "~" but instead want to use the "fuzzy" parameters as defined here: [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) (search for "fuzzy", "fuzzy_prefix_length")

However this is not working:

```
POST *person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
    "query": "micheal",
    "fuzziness": 2,
    "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
    "fuzzy_prefix_length": 2
  }
 } 
}
```

Even though this does:

> GET *person/_search
>   {
>     "query": {
>       "fuzzy": {
>         "_all": {
>          "value": "micheal",
>          "fuzziness": 2,
>          "prefix_length": 2,
>          "max_expansions": 50
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }

I have also tried the below which also does not work:

```
QueryStringQueryBuilder queryStringQueryBuilder = new QueryStringQueryBuilder(submittedQuery);

if (elasticQuery.getFuzzy()) {
  queryStringQueryBuilder.fuzziness(Fuzziness.AUTO);
  queryStringQueryBuilder.fuzzyPrefixLength(3);
  queryStringQueryBuilder.fuzzyMaxExpansions(20);
}
```

Comment: Isn't fuzziness using Levenshtein distance, there's a big difference between michael and firstName:Michael https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/common-options.html#fuzziness

Comment: Ok. That aside, "michael~" should be similar to "michael" with "fuzzyness=2". Maybe my misunderstanding is that adding "fuzzyness:2" just configures the amount of fuzzyness but doesn't make the query fuzzy.